# Remote name could not be resolved . Error with WCF Services

Tags: asp.net, wcf, publish

I have two asp.net web applications talking to each other through WCF. Two applications are developed in two different localhosts. Once the developement is successful, we Published them to same test server. Now when one of the application is trying to call the service in another applciation .. it throwing error..remote name could not be resolved.
Can any one suggest me how to resolve this?

Comment: please post the configs? are they hosted on the same port? How are you  creating proies? do you set the url of the proxies? you problem either lies in config or setting the url of the proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dhawalk mentioned, confgs will be very helpful.

Generally, this error usually means that your "service address" is wrong - check the value of your client's endpoint. 
By default, you'll find it in client's app.config, in section of serviceModel.

Something like (for basicHTTPBinding)

```
. . .     
<client>
       <endpoint address="http://YOUR_SERVER_NAME/SERVICE_NAME" ...
. . .
```

Ensure that you can access this url from your "client's" application

Comment: Thanks Dhawalk and evgenyl. This is a very late reply..but i thought some one might find it useful...I changed the address from "h t t p ://servername/service.svc" to "h t t p://IPADDRESS/service.svc" and it is working now